# Cumsum returning a vector in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, scipy, cumsum

I have my array, say: `[10, 6, 4, 12]`.
I am interested in finding a vector of cumulative sums, i.e.:
[10, 16, 20, 32].
Obvious approach would be to use a for loop:

```
r = []
for ind in range(4):
  r.append(s[ind])  # s is [10, 6, 4, 12]
r = cumsum(r)
```

However, this seems really inefficient. I want to ask if there is a pre-defined function or I should specify specific arguments in cumsum.

Comment: I don't think I understand; is the code you posted supposed to be your attempt at *implementing* `cumsum`? If not, you don't need to make a copy in that strange way; you could use `s` directly. But if the question is simply "did `scipy` implement `cumsum` for me already", then the answer is a) if you didn't know, then how did you come up with that name??? b) did you try putting `scipy cumsum` into a search engine???

Comment: Anyway, you do understand, I hope, that `[10, 6, 4, 12]` is **not** an "array", nor a "vector"; it is a (built-in) **list**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, I should have my data and just tried to make a toy excample. I think the answer satisfies my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways like `np.cumsum` or python 3.2+ you can use [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

By Itertool:

```
l = [10, 6, 4, 12]

from itertools import accumulate

print(list(accumulate(l)))
```

**output:**

```
[10, 16, 20, 32]
```

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.cumsum(l))
```

**output:**

```
[10, 16, 20, 32]
```

Answer (score 0):

Libless solution:

```
s = [10, 6, 4, 12]
r = [sum(s[:i+1]) for i in range(len(s))]
```

Output:

```
[10, 16, 20, 32]
```

Comment: note that this is O(N^2) complexity, you only want to do this for small lists